# Angular set base href at runtime

Tags: angular, routes, href, radix

my Angular 7 app is deployed on a cluster of servers, and it's deployed on multiple servers:

```
http://server1:8081/my-app
http://server2:8081/my-app
```

In addition it's also available at a load balancer that forward the request to an available sub-server:

```
https://my-balancer.com/apps/my-app
```

I'm using PathLocationStrategy and I'd like to make it works on all the URLs.

The problem I'm having is with the base href attribute, because its value should be set at runtime:

```
http://server1:8081/my-app           <-- base_href should be /my-app/
https://my-balancer.com/apps/my-app  <-- base_href should be /apps/my-app/
```

Is there a way to set the base_href attribute at runtime, for example building its value from the location.href ?

I've tried adding the APP_BASE_HREF provider to the AppModule, but angular seem ignoring it.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: how have you tried adding the APP_BASE_HREF? Could you post some code of that?

Answer (score 0):

As the `<base>` tag is set in the `index.html` file, outside of our `AppComponent`, I don't think Angular will provide a specific service to make this possible. So, the only option left is to do it manually inside `AppComponent`

```
ngOnInit() {
   const base = document.head.querySelector('base');
   base.href = 'whatever you want';
}
```

This should do the job for you.

Comment: Thanks, I tried, but it doesn't seem to work, the base href is set correctly as 'whater you want', but the browser seems to ignore it when it downloads the static resources

Comment: Interesting, I will look into it later

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify at runtime the `dist/index.html` file by adding a bash script to your server instance like this:

```
#/bin/bash

sed -i 's/base href="\/my-app\/"/base href="'$1'"/' index.html
```

Pass the new **href** value as a parameter to the script.

Hope it helps.